# Prove that middle cancellation implies that the group is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Suppose that $G$ is a group with the property that for every choice of elements in $G$, $axb=cxd$ implies $ab=cd$.
>
> Prove that $G$ is Abelian.
>
> (Middle cancellation implies commutativity).

To be an Abelian group, it is required that $\forall a,b \in G$, $a. b=b .a$

Can I request for a **hint** to this question? I'm not sure how to get started on this one.

Comment: To be clear, $a,b,c,d,x \in G$?

Comment: @AdamFrancey It is not stated explicitly. Question is word for word from the text.

Comment: Yes at this point, the chapter deals only with finite group. So I will assume so.@CuddlyCuttlefish

Comment: (realized it was a silly question :) )

Comment: I am not sure whey the post is tagged (finite-groiups), but the assumption that $G$ is finite does not seem necessary here.

Comment: See also [Suppose that $G$ is a group with the property that for every choice of elements in $G$, $axb=cxd$ implies $ab=cd$. Prove that $G$ is Abelian.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500530/suppose-that-g-is-a-group-with-the-property-that-for-every-choice-of-elements)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Given $a$ and $b$, find an element $x$ such that $axb=bxa$. (I can think of two $x$s that would work.)

Comment: Your rephrasing of the question helps a lot!
$x=(a^{-1}bb^{-1})$ is one solution

Comment: That's just equal to $x=a^{-1}$, isn't it? In any case, yes, $x=a^{-1}$ is what I was thinking of (the other option was $x=b^{-1}$).

Comment: By simplifying, yes.

Comment: So, to finish: We know that $aa^{-1}b=ba^{-1}a$ is always true. Thus, by the condition in the problem, we get…

Comment: We get an Abelian group by the hypothesis that $axb=cxd$ implies $ab=cd$

Morever, $c=b$ and $d=a$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extremely vague hint:

Define $x = ab$. Then $xa = aba$...