# Intersection of two centralizers

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group with the property that for every choice of elements in $G$, $axb = cxd$ implies $ab = cd$. Is $G$ abelian?

My approach: I take $a=c$ and $b=d$ in the above and trying to find some $x$. Now if $x$ commutes with both $a$ and $b$ then it obvious. So my questions are:

1. When do any two centralizers of a group intersect non trivially?
2. How do I solve the question?

Comment: Why don’t you take $c=b$ and $d=a$?

Comment: Actually I take c=b and d=a, it's a silly mistake

Comment: This was answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500530/suppose-that-g-is-a-group-with-the-property-that-for-every-choice-of-elements?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But there is a more general question here ( question 1)

Comment: But it's hard to know exactly what you asking in Question 1. This holds for example when the group has nontrivial centre. So you could ask are there any examples of groups $G$ with a trivial centre for which $C_G(a) \cap C_G(b) \ne 1$ for all $a,b \in G$. I would guess that the answer is yes, but I don't know an example.